# Will start using cron jobs after two years result in problems?

Tags: cron

I would like to start using the magento cronjob to send out review reminders automatically. Cron jobs have never run before (since its installation two years ago) on this installation if I'm correct. I wonder what will happen. Can this result in problems?

Comment: hey @rxt, keep us updated on your question. You've posted a popular question so be sure to let us know what happened :)

Comment: I have the cron jobs working, and nothing strange has happened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It shouldn't be an issue, check the table `cron_schedule` in the database. The uncompleted tasks that are in there will be executed so in case you want to make a fresh start just TRUNCATE that table.

After that you can set up either `cron.php` or `cron.sh` and it will rebuild the table with the current cron tasks.

I would recommend installing [Aoe Scheduler](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html) if you want more insight in what cronjobs are running on your Magento installation.

Comment: Depends on how large the log tables have grown to. They can be so large that running the log table maintenance can cause memory exhaustion. The log maintenance script in the shell/ folder may have to be run and if it crashes, then the tables will have to be manually truncated. If it's a reasonably active site, the log tables are going to be huge after not having been cleaned for two years.

Comment: You're right, might be smart to truncate those manually before running the first cron.

Comment: Moral of the story, always set a cron job on the server to run Magento's cron.sh or cron.php trigger from the very beginning. Your customers will love you for not having the website speed decrease as the logs fill and your hosting provider will love you for not wasting disk space.

Comment: I had problems getting the cron jobs running. The linux cron did its job, but for some reason magento cron tasks were not executed. After installing the AOE scheduler all problems were solved, without doing anything else. I haven't noticed any problems with performance or anything since then.